# jquery ajax issue. strange behavour in .done() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im seeing some very odd stuff in a simple ajax/jquery code I wrote and I can't explain why Im seeing what Im seeing.

I have a php file called complete.php, the only thing this does at the moment is:

```
echo "saved";
```

I have a jquery ajax call, which has a .done() function, which looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "complete.php",
        data: "id=someIdHere",
        }).done(function(d){

         alert(d);

          if(d == "saved"){
                alert('loading done');
          }else{
                alert('error');
          }
    });
```

My firebug confirms the response from the complete.php is 'saved'.

when I typeof the 'd' response,  it is of type 'string',

however for some reason, the alert I get in the .done() function, is 'error' and not 'loading done'.

the 'alert(d)' just before the if statement gives 'saved'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: So if logged the `typeof d` sucessfully as "string", have you tried logging `d` itself? What is it?

Comment: yes, it gives 'saved' as I though it would/should

Comment: Using firebug, place a breakpoint in the `.done()` function and check the value of `d`. There might be more than just what you hope.

Comment: try console.log(d) to see what it might be. It could be you need to do if (d.toString()=="saved")...

Comment: iv tried .toString(), but it makes no difference, and the type is already oftype string. Im sure the code is correct, all very odd

Comment: I can't see why it should, but may be worth checking there isn't any additional whitespace being added to `d`: `if($.trim(d) == "saved")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd but Iv found the issue.

my php was

```
echo "saved";
```

which is right, however when I debugged the return as per @mplungjan suggestion, the return was " saved" (with white space) this was odd as the php had no white space, I then changed the php to

`echo trim("saved");`

but when I again debugged the return, it again was " saved" (with the white space)

No idea why the white space is being applied, but I have resolved it by replacing the white space in the return / .done() function

I wont select this as the answer, but if anyone knows hoe the white space could have been added Id love to know.

Im using firefox 18 on mountain lion

Comment: any whitespace before the `<?`?

Comment: @dan-dvorak there was. Iv removed this. still comes back with the whitespace before the 'saved'

Answer (score 1):

You should use a more robust return type, such as JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 'saved',
));
```

Then in your success handler:

```
if (d.status == 'saved') { ... }
```

Comment: Hi, I fully agree. I was wrote the code just as a means to confirm the response from the php script, then couldn't understand why it was not turning as expected, so though it made sense to put it here in case anyone met the same issue. production code will be json

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "complete.php",
    data: "id=someIdHere",
    success: function(){ alert('loading done'); },
    error: function(){ alert('error'); }
    });
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this as the `success` function would be fully managed by the `ajax` rather than rely on the jqXHR implementation. You can also use your variable in the `success`...

Comment: You can also use the `complete` option of the `ajax` method if you need to do something in both both cases.